# Plotting clustered np.array by using plt.scatter

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot, hierarchical-clustering

I have a `numpy` vector in the shape of 17520 and only one column, I want to plot it by using `plt.scatter` and I don`t know if I should change the shape or not.
My np vector consists of three values 0,1 and 2, where each value represents the cluster number after using hierarchical clustering.
After reading the Excel file and doing some pre-processing, here is my code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
plt.title("Customer Dendograms")
dend = shc.dendrogram(shc.linkage(data1, method='ward'))
cluster = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=3, affinity='euclidean', linkage='ward')
X=cluster.fit_predict(data1)
```

The variable X holds the np vector that I want to plot and the shape is 17520.
Please any help to be able to plot the data in which the 0 values are red, the ones are blue, and the twos are green.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (assuming that `data1` has shape `17520 x 2` and `X` has shape `17520 x 1`).

```
redClass = data1[X == 0]
blueClass = data1[X == 1] 
greenClass = data1[X == 2]
plt.scatter(redClass[:, 0], redClass[:, 1], c='r')
plt.scatter(blueClass[:, 0], blueClass[:, 1], c='b')
plt.scatter(greenClass[:, 0], greenClass[:, 1], c='g')
plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks a lot but the shape of data1 is 17520 x 25 and when I ran the code above, it gave me the error TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Comment: How would you visualize a 25 dimensional vector as a scatter plot? Perhaps you'll need to do dimensionality reduction using PCA.